# Can I include dll in exe (in Visual Studio)?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, include, release, exec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET windows application, can it be compressed into a single .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126611/net-windows-application-can-it-be-compressed-into-a-single-exe)

To run my App I need `AxInterop.WMPLib.dll` and `Interop.WMPLib.dll` that are located in Debug and Release folder. Is there any way to include those dlls into exe so my app is available in one file only?

Comment: Even though this is possible I don't really like it. The point of shared libraries is that they are shared between programs. What about downloading them when your program discovers they are not already installed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As long as your DLLs are .NET assemblies, then [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) should be able to combine your exe and all of its dependencies into a single file.

Comment: This is noted on the ILMerge page as well but for WPF apps use this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can use a tool like boxedapp or thinstall...

Answer (score 4):

I also recommend  boxedapp. It's great app!

Comment: I prefer to use BoxedApp. It is so simpl!!!

Comment: Except it costs around $500CAD.

Answer (score 0):

Include them as embedded.  You can then extract them at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I left out the code to write the file out...

```
FileStream so=new FileStream("c:\\\wherever\\\x.dll",FileMode.Create);

so.Write(buf,0,ssize);

so.Close();
```

No extra utilities required.

Answer (score -2):

For example, add x.dll to the project and set its Build Action to Embedded Resource.

To extract:

```
 string AppPath=Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
 Assembly ThisAssembly=Assembly.LoadFrom(AppPath);
 System.IO.Stream fs=ThisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("yourproectname.x.dll");
 int ssize=(int)fs.Length;
 byte [] buf=new byte[ssize];
 fs.Read(buf,0,ssize);
 fs.Close();
```

Comment: The first two lines are an unnecessary complication of "Assembly thisAssembly =Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();". Then there is this line missing at the end: "Assembly.Load(buf);". Finally, this is a horrible solution because you can then access the loaded assembly through reflection only.