# Deploy a .exe and dependent .dll

Tags: c#, .net

I have console project. It is developed in VS2010. It uses Mysql.net connector.

When I was developing in my machine, Every thing worked fine.

I copied the .exe to my friends laptop and tried to run it, but I got an error telling that Mysql.data.client not found.

I copied all the dlls in to the project folder. Everything worked fine.

Is there any way I can can build the .exe in such a way that I dont have to copy the Mysql.data.client to the other machine.

"Building .exe with all dependencies." Is that possible?

Please let me know.

Comment: Here you go: [ILMerge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476993?sort=newest)

Comment: possible duplicate of [can I include dll in exe (in visual studio) ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476993/can-i-include-dll-in-exe-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Yeah, my post below pointed him there...

Comment: Any adverse side effects of using dlls merged to one huge .exe file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Setup Project to add to your Solution.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

This will create an installable application (.msi) with all the included dependencies of your project.