# Include project reference in debug

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, reference

I built an online login program which connects to my online MySQL db. In my application i have used the MySQL.Data file as a reference since the program needed the file to connect to the online MySQL server. Now my question; when I take my program from 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MYPROJECT\MYPROJECT\bin\Debug' and copy that file to a completely other computer, I get an error message saying that the MySQL.Data file is missing. I want to know how I can include the MySQL.Data file in my project compile. If you need further details I am happy to provide them.

Comment: ~~~~~~This is VB 2010~~~~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Solution Explorer of your project, you have the point *References*, where the `MySql.Data.dll` should occur. Right-click it and select *Properties*, and in the Properties make sure that *Copy Local* is set to `True`.

Then, the `MySql.Data.dll` file will always be copied to your `bin/Debug` folder.

If you deploy your program, you have to copy that dll, too. Then everything will work on the other computer.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks :D but is there are way which I can compile the MySQL.DLL file into the program? because it will be quite annoying copying 2 files for users..

Comment: If you want something like that, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476993/can-i-include-dll-in-exe-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

You can build a setup project (installer), or copy the mysql.data.dll file with your exe (basicly everything in your bin/{config} directory).

Comment: Hi, I only have 2 folders inside my bin directory, Debug & Release (The release folder is empty) btw this is VB 2010