# Including dll's in the exe?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, dll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET windows application, can it be compressed into a single .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126611/net-windows-application-can-it-be-compressed-into-a-single-exe)

I have a project that relies on several dlls and once I compile it, it requires that I run the .exe in the same folder with the dlls. Can I package them together so I don't have to do that?

For reference, I'm using C#

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961357/using-ilmerge-with-net-4-libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-B4AD-4EAE-87CF-B14AE6A939B0&displaylang=en) to combine them into one.

Comment: See, for example, http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Using-ILMerge-to-Combine-Application-Components/