# C# Compile dll into exe

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Including dll's in the exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753292/including-dlls-in-the-exe)

I am referencing a dll in my project. It runs fine, but in the /bin/release/ folder contain an exe and a dll. when I remove the dll the exe won't work. How can I compile the dll into the exe, so I do not have to worried about the deployment?

Thnks.

Comment: dup:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476993/can-i-include-dll-in-exe-in-visual-studio

Comment: Thnaks all, found this useful : http://ilmergegui.codeplex.com/

Comment: Also duplicate of [stackoverflow.com/questions/189549](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this MSR page](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) for information on ILMerge as well as a clever alternative documented by Jeffrey Richter.

Answer (score 1):

DLL's are not statically linked (as the name itself suggests) otherwise it won't be a DLL :)

There are two ways to get a monolithic binary:

1. Include the source of the DLL in your project itself.
2. Use ILMerge