# How to create a dll that includes all the others?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dll, dllexport

At the moment of creating a project of type "Library of Classes, usually one can generate a dll when compiling, but how could I generate a dll without losing others that I already have included?

I explain with an example: It turns out that Nuget downloaded an S22.Imap dll with the one I worked with, later I generated the dll in the traditional way that I explained in the beginning, but when I wanted to work with dll in another computer, I got errors that were not I found functions that contained the S22.IMAP dll. So to solve this problem, I had to copy the dll of my project, S22.IMAP in an additional way in a specific path of the other computer.

[image]

**My question is:**

How could you generate a dll that includes the ones included in the project you were working with?

Comment: See [ILMerge for how to combine assemblies](https://github.com/Microsoft/ILMerge). While this tool 'solves' the direct question, it may not best solve the task..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the referred 3rd party dlls (S22.Imap.dll in your example) will be copied to the output folder together with your own dll file (let's say a.dll) when you build your project. That means you should always copy them together (S22 + a.dll) to the place you want to refer them, on another computer/folder/place.

If you really want to make them only one file (although it is not recommended), you can set the S22 one as some "nested resource". Then you will get only one a.dll file and the S22 one is inside the a.dll. See below page for some reference:

[Embedding one dll inside another as an embedded resource and then calling it from my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96732/embedding-one-dll-inside-another-as-an-embedded-resource-and-then-calling-it-fro)

AND, [ILMerge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) is some tool that can help you do so.

Answer (score 3):

In general, ***you don't***. A DLL is a *dynamic* linked library, and you would normally only combine static libraries during a build. Here is an [answer on the difference between static and dynamic linking](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/243164/why-are-there-two-different-kinds-of-linking-i-e-static-and-dynamic).

Typically you would include all the DLLs you need in the installer package. If you use Visual Studio to create the installer, it can detect the dependencies for you. When you run the installer, all of the necessary DLLs are deployed. Nearly all commercial .NET software follows this pattern.

It is *possible* to merge an assembly into another assembly using a tool called [ILMerge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924488/c-sharp-compile-dll-into-exe). This would be a ***very*** unusual thing to do, and could cause issues with intellectual property and code signing, so it is not recommended.