# how do i force a DLL to be built with the exe so there is only one file?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, exec

i have a simple app in c#. i would like the DLL to be "inside" the exe file. how do i do this?

Comment: Do you also build the dll or is it something you depend on from another source?

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: @ed its less confusing for the user

Comment: Really?  Why does the user care about DLL's at all?  (HINT: They shouldn't)

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET windows application, can it be compressed into a single .exe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126611/net-windows-application-can-it-be-compressed-into-a-single-exe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en) does exactly what you are looking for

---

the page is a little misleading, ILMerge works on V3 and V4 assemblies per its [actual webpage](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx)

> ILMerge should work just fine with
>   newer versions of .NET. Just use the
>   option: /targetplatform:v4,. For
>   version 3.5, you probably don't need
>   to set the target platform, but you
>   may need to add the v3.5 framework
>   directory as a /lib option so that
>   assemblies from there can be found.
>   (Unless they're in the GAC in which
>   case they'll be found anyway.) To run
>   ILMerge in the v4.0 runtime, use this
>   config file.

---

To answer how do you use it from your question in the other answer

> Usage: ilmerge [/lib:directory]*
>   [/log[:filename]] [/keyfile:filename
>   [/delaysign]]
>   [/internalize[:filename]] [/t[arget]
>   :(library|exe|winexe)] [/closed]
>   [/ndebug] [/ver:version] [/copyattrs
>   [/allowMultiple]] [/xmldocs]
>   [/attr:filename] [/ta
>   rgetplatform:[,]
>   | /v1 | /v1.1 | /v2 | /v4]
>   [/useFullPublicKeyForReferences]
>   [/wildcards] [/zeroPe Kind]
>   [/allowDup:type]* [/union] [/align:n]
>   /out:filename 
>   [...]

So `ilmerge /out:Combined.exe mainFile.exe  otherDll.dll` for your case as most of the defaults should be fine

Comment: @herrow: The newer versions will support other things - what version of .NET are you using, and what type of application is it?

Comment: @reed winforms version 3.5NET

Comment: htmlagilitypack is probably latest version

Comment: I have used ILMerge on 3.5 apps fine. give it a try.

Comment: @reed i succesfully merge the two files, however when i open the resulting exe, it ALSO opens a command prompt, have you see this weird behavior?

Comment: Try adding the switch /target:winexe

Comment: @scott btw you showing me the insane usage didnt help at all since i have NO CLUE how to decode that. its like that stupid mysql official site that gives you the crazy syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html - COMPLETELY USELESS

Comment: That is why i added a copy of what you needed out of the usage screen right after it (i did miss the winexe but we got that eventually)

Answer (score 2):

[ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx) can do this for .NET assemblies - though it has some limitations with certain types of assemblies (such as WPF Assemblies).

You can, alternatively, [use the assembly as a resource and load it on demand](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx), or use one of the many commercial obfuscators which support assembly merging.  Many of the third party options support more elaborate depedency merging and/or dependency embedding.  A good example of this is [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/features), which supports both options.

Comment: +1.  You beat me to it AGAIN!  My new goal in life is to learn to type faster than Reed Copsey!  ;-)

Comment: @herrow: What type of DLL is it?  Is it native/managed/.NET (v?)

Comment: @herrow: It should work for a WinForms assembly...  You can merge that with your executable fairly easily using ILMerge.

Comment: @reed id otn know, its htmlagilitypack

Comment: @herrow: Download it, and read the docs - it's a command line app that does it.  (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en)

Comment: @reed i succesfully merge the two files, however when i open the resulting exe, it ALSO opens a command prompt, have you see this weird behavior?

Comment: @herrow: Make sure that you use `/target:winexe` on the command line.  It sounds like you targetted a console application.