# Portable .net applications

Tags: .net, portable-executable, portable-applications

By portable I mean in installer-less application kind of way.

Can I somehow bundle the .net framework (or just the assemblies it depends on) with my application so it could run on any Windows system without installing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the same as [Can a .NET windows application be compressed into a single .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126611/net-windows-application-can-it-be-compressed-into-a-single-exe)

Comment: Yeah this is pretty much the same question. I need to lrn2search. This question may be closed as a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

No. But once the .NET framework is installed, many applications can be "xcopy" deployed.

Note that [several versions of Windows do bundle the .NET framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pmarcu/archive/2010/02/05/which-version-of-net-is-built-into-windows.aspx), but it's recommended not to depend on this because everything past .NET 2.0 is optional.