# Run exe unless make setup (embed dll to exe)

Tags: c#, .net, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET windows application, can it be compressed into a single .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126611/net-windows-application-can-it-be-compressed-into-a-single-exe)

I have a project and I am using a lot of .dll files in this project. When i try the run my project on another computer it's not working. Because i am using only .exe. I think I have to make setup project. But I want to run my program without making setup project. How can I embed .dll files into my exe?
I am using Visual Studio 2010.
By the way sorry for my English but google translated English worse than mine.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just copy your dll file with exe file into the same directory.
and you can use the [ILMerge util](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569269.aspx)

you can download it from  [msdn](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en)

Comment: Can not I embed the dll files into exe?

Comment: Do you have a source code of you dll files?

Comment: use the utility that I wrote above

Answer (score 1):

Use **[ILMerge.exe](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx)** and you can merge your EXE and DLL together.

---

You can also use **[netz.exe](http://madebits.com/netz/index.php)** as an alternative EXE compressor & packer.

Answer (score 0):

Just right-click your project in Visual Studio, choose Project Properties -> Resources -> Add Resource -> Add Existing File…
And include the code below to your App.xaml.cs or equivalent.

```
public App()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve +=new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
}

System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string dllName = args.Name.Contains(',') ? args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(',')) : args.Name.Replace(".dll","");

    dllName = dllName.Replace(".", "_");

    if (dllName.EndsWith("_resources")) return null;

    System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(GetType().Namespace + ".Properties.Resources", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    byte[] bytes = (byte[])rm.GetObject(dllName);

    return System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(bytes);
}
```

Here's my original blog post:
http://codeblog.larsholm.net/2011/06/embed-dlls-easily-in-a-net-assembly/