# Include DLL into Exe

Tags: c#

I am new to **C#**.
I am not a good programmer but I have worked on some projects which were in **Delphi7**. In Delphi there is one option; compile the class files to create **.dcu**. Those **.dcu** can be used without having the actual code with any other project in Delphi and after build **.dcu** files need not no given to end user.

Now my actual Question,

*Is there any way where I can create some compiled file from my C# class and use that compiled unit with some other project in C# ?*

I already tried to create dll and use. Nice Idea, but I don't want to give any other file than Configuration File and Executable file. Since, I created dll that needs to give with application.

I also tried to create a setup of application which build executable, configuration file and dll together. while executing, it extract itself in %temp% folder and executes from there only. So, In this case I am not able to set the configuration file's values.

Again the same question,

*Is there any way where I can create some compiled file from my C# class and use that compiled unit with some other project in C# ?*



Please suggest the solution

Thanks

Comment: this is one of the most duplicated questions here. I myself have closed over 5 such questions.

Comment: nawfal,Its not duplicate question. Its slightly different from other questions. Till now I have not found the solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Make it into a `.dll`. And then add that `.dll` as a reference in whatever project you want by clicking on `References` and then selecting `Add Reference`, and then in the `Browse` tab navigate to your `.dll` and select add. You will now have access.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. But as I already said that, I don't want to give any other file than Configuration File and Executable file. Since, I created dll that needs to give with application.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to combine all your DLLs and the EXE to a single EXE?
You can use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630). 

For more options take a look this question: [Can a .NET windows application be compressed into a single .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126611/net-windows-application-can-it-be-compressed-into-a-single-exe)

Comment: In your case I assume you don't need any configuration file for picking values dynamically. In my case it is there. Since a merged exe runs from %temp% directory but configuration file is in some other directory.