# How to compile localization DLLs (MyLibrary.resources.dll) into a single DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, localization

Using C# .NET with COM interop in VS2012, I'm developing a common library  for use in several other programs. To keep the integration simple, I would like to keep the entire library down to one DLL. One of the features of this library is localization. It has string tables with messages in multiple languages, each language having it's own ResX file.

Presently, a `MyLibrary.resources.dll` is being created for each language and placed in its own subdirectory, like this:

```
Release\MyLibrary.dll
Release\ja\MyLibrary.resources.dll
Release\fr\MyLibrary.resources.dll
```

What I want to see is just this:

```
Release\MyLibrary.dll
```

Here are my current ResX settings.

[image: ResX settings]

I have tried using `ResXFileCodeGenerator` and `GlobalResourceProxyGenerator` for the "Custom Tool" generators. I also tried a few options for "Build Action" including Compile, but so far only Embedded Resource works. Other than that I'm not sure what else to try or if I'm on the right track. There aren't really that many settings to work with.

I am aware that there are a [variety of tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126611/net-windows-application-can-it-be-compressed-into-a-single-exe) that may work to do this after building the DLL, but I'm looking for a compile-time solution. Third party tools are challenging from a maintenance standpoint -- I will not be the only one updating this library.

Comment: Is it too much to ask for the other developers to install e.g. ILMerge as part of their development environment? Then you can configure it to run automatically as a post-build step. Requiring all developers to install all build tools, third-party or not, doesn't seem like an unreasonable requirement to me, although I'm not sure what your situation is. (Disclaimer: I have no experience with your issue.)

Comment: You can't have this out of the box. That is not how loading localization assemblies work. You could however write your own resourcemanager that doesn't rely on several assemblies but on something else (a file, or database, or just one assembly).

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @webbexpert, I was not. I had to give up and move on. I'm leaving the resources in their own subfolders. I will accept yours as the answer as it seems to describe the process. With no one else weighing in, that's the best we have. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main ways of embedding libraries into a single DLL or executable. The first uses ILMerge, combines all assemblies as if it was a single assembly; the second is dynamically loading dependencies from embedded resource(s) at runtime (offers a bit more flexibility, but has its own set of pros and cons). The sample project is intended to be portable (the only dependency is Powershell -- all required libraries are included in the project).

It's important to know the difference between the two techniques. I've written articles outlining both approaches with a sample project on github for both approaches.

**Articles:**

[Assembly Loading: Combine Assemblies & Executables Using ilMerge](http://www.webbexpert.com/assembly-loading-combine-assemblies-executables-using-ilmerge-2-of-3/)

AND

[Assembly Loading: Dynamic Assembly Loading & Compression](http://www.webbexpert.com/assembly-loading-dynamic-assembly-loading-3-of-3/)

**Sample Project:**

[Application Demonstrating Both ILMerge and Runtime Loading of Embedded Assemblies](https://github.com/webbexpert/Public.Process)

If you have any questions regarding either approach, don't hesitate to get in touch. I'll gladly refine the posts based on your feedback.

Comment: Thanks for enumerating the options. I will look at your articles and sample code. Since the (default) resource file is embedded automatically, there is definitely a third solution: modify the resource manager somehow to embed the languages by default. I have been exploring all three options this week, but I don't yet have a working solution except a hack I developed to bypass the resource manager. ILMerge is throwing an exception, and there additional challenges dynamic loading resources for a Class Library (not executable). On top of all that, the COM services have been a huge pain.

Comment: Sounds like ilMerge might be the best choice (it generally is); what is the exception it is throwing? I might be able to shed some light on it. If you come up with an elegant solution please keep me posted :)