# Embed all System.Text.Json dlls to final exe

Tags: c#

what is the best way to embed all of this .dll from system.text.json into my final .exe file?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLzkZ.jpg

Comment: You should use install shield application to zip all files in one exe file.

Comment: Do you mean you want to fuse DLLs _into_ the .EXE so that there is only one file or are you talking about creating a _self-executing_ installer?

Comment: yes @MickyD I want to merge them into one file

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126611/can-a-net-windows-application-be-compressed-into-a-single-exe

Answer (score 1):

With .NET Core 3, you can use `<PublishSingleFile>` in your .csproj to create a single executable. You can also use `<PublishTrimmed>` to reduce the size of the executable by only including what your application actually uses.

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingATinyNETCore30EntirelySelfcontainedSingleExecutable.aspx

If you're on .NET Framework, you can use [ILMerge](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge).

Comment: I'm using .net framework 4

Comment: I added an alternative for .NET Framework 4.